# viewpager get stuck while swiping

Tags: android, android-viewpager

[image: viewpager]

Hi everyone,

viewpager sometimes get stuck while swiping through articles 
Here is the code:

```
@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Preferences.applyTheme(this);


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.detail);

    feed = (RSSFeed) getIntent().getExtras().get("feed");

    pos = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("pos");


    adapter = new DescAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);


    pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    pager.setCurrentItem(pos);

}       


public class DescAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public DescAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {

        super(fm);

    }


    @Override

    public int getCount() {

        return feed.getItemCount();

    }


    @Override

    public Fragment getItem(int position) {


        ArticleFragment frag = new ArticleFragment();


        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

        bundle.putSerializable("feed", feed);

        bundle.putInt("pos", position);

        frag.setArguments(bundle);


        return frag;


    }


}
```

The source code is here if You need more code details

https://github.com/enricocid/lffl-feed-reader

**Thanks for any reply**

Answer (score 2):

Try `adapter = new DescAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());`

Comment: getChildFragmentManager() is on Fragment, not FragmentActivity